# Regarding the g++ linker error "undefined reference to"

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors

I am new to C++ and, for practice, have written my own vector class. The header file, Vector.h, is

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H_INCLUDED
#define VECTOR_H_INCLUDED

#include <cstddef>
#include <memory>

template <class T> class Vector {

    public:
        Vector();
       ~Vector();

    // code

};

#endif
```

The corresponding source file, Vector.cpp, is

```
#include "Vector.h"

template <class T> Vector<T>::Vector() 
{ 
    // code 
}

template <class T> Vector<T>::~Vector() 
{ 
    // code 
}

// code
```

The test file, VectorDemo.cpp, is

```
#include "Vector.h"

int main() 
{
    Vector<int> v;
    return 0;
}
```

In Bash I type

```
g++ -c Vector.cpp VectorDemo.cpp
g++ -o VectorDemo Vector.o VectorDemo.o
```

and get the following error

```
VectorDemo.o: In function `main':
VectorDemo.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `Vector<int>::Vector()'
VectorDemo.cpp:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `Vector<int>::~Vector()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How do I fix this issue and why is this happening?

Comment: I think you need a better system than `g++`-ing a bunch of stuff. Considered a `Makefile` or `CMakefile`?

Answer (score 1):

Template classes must be defined *exclusively* in the header. They cannot be compiled separately.

The reason for this is the compiler can only produce machine code for a specific instantiation of this template. The `Vector.cpp` file basically compiles to nothing, it's just a bunch of otherwise unused definitions.

Since these definitions don't amount to anything, they aren't instantiated within `Vector.cpp`, they're effectively ignored. When it comes time to compile `VectorDemo.cpp` they're missing, hence the linker errors.

Comment: That's very helpful, thank you.